# How to Search a Map Key in a List : Scala

Tags: scala

I have a `Map[key:String, value:String]` and a `List[(s1:String,s2:String,s3:String)]`

I want to get(extract) the 3rd string  3rd field s3 from the entire Row(tuple).

Mostly it will be having 1-to-1 mapping with the key in map and the 3 field Row in the List.

Comment: how you want to extract s3 from list??? s3 from all tuples or only those which exist in map??

Comment: one which matched the key so to be more specific Map.k1 == List(s1) once i get the row i want 's3' by matching Map.k1 == List.s1

Comment: Gotcha. You'd have to filter `if map.containes(s1)`. See answer below

Answer (score 0):

**If you are looking for to extract the field in tuple if some other field is in your Map,**

- you'd have to `.filter` through the list to match the keys in `Map` and
- map over to get required element of tuple.

example,

```
scala> val customers = Map("customer1" -> "location", 
                           "customer2" -> "location2", 
                           "customer-strange" -> "canada-strange")
customers: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(customer1 -> location, customer2 -> location2, customer-strange -> canada-strange)

scala> val orders = Seq(("customer1", "shirts", "pants"), 
                        ("customer2", "guitar", "drum"), 
                        ("customer-not-in-map", "whatever-1", "whatever-2"))
orders: Seq[(String, String, String)] = List((customer1,shirts,pants), (customer2,guitar,drum), (customer-not-in-map,whatever-1,whatever-2))

scala> orders.collect { case (s1, s2, s3) if customers.contains(s1) => s3 }
res2: Seq[String] = List(pants, drum)
```

The other version is

```
scala> orders.filter { case (s1, s2, s3) => customers.contains(s1) }
             .map { case (s1, s2, s3) => s3}
res5: Seq[String] = List(pants, drum)
```

Try working example - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/prayagupd/Hz4BDU02RQm1AzJZl73lAA/5

Comment: Not working.
val map1 = Map("1" -> "abc", "2" -> "def", "3"->"hij")
val list = List(("1","abc","comment1"), ("2","def","comment2"), (("3","abc","comment1")))

val res = list.filter{
  case(s1,s2,s3) => map1.contains(s1)
}.map{case(s1,s2,s3) => s3}

println(res)

Output : 
-----------------
list: List[(String, String, String)] = List((1,abc,comment1), (2,def,comment2), (3,abc,comment1))




res: List[String] = List(comment1, comment2, comment1)




List(comment1, comment2, comment1)
res1: Unit = ()

Comment: It should and it does. see working example here - https://scastie.scala-lang.org/prayagupd/Hz4BDU02RQm1AzJZl73lAA/5

Comment: i don't want entire row in return i just that 3rd field

Comment: Yes i ran it. But its not what i was looking for. Thanks tough i figured out myself